# get package names (untouched) after a fresh install of Ubuntu OS.. Reinstall the initial packages and remove the additional packages those are added

Tags: apt, package-management

I am at beginning stage of understanding/ learning Ubuntu OS..
Started Using Ubuntu from 17.04 release..

I have several times Reinstalled the Installed OS while learning, breaking the OS.. I felt Its quite time consuming reinstalling the OS..

Thoughts:

say, for example when I installed the OS Ubuntu 18.04.3 minimal installation.
I will run `apt list --installed` and It will give some package names..

for example, some part of above command is

```
libperlio-gzip-perl/bionic,now 0.19-1build3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpgm-5.2-0/bionic,now 5.2.122~dfsg-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libphonenumber7/bionic,now 7.1.0-5ubuntu5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpipeline1/bionic,now 1.5.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpixman-1-0/bionic,now 0.34.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libplist3/bionic,now 2.0.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libplymouth4/bionic-updates,now 0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpng16-16/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.6.34-1ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpolkit-agent-1-0/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpolkit-backend-1-0/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpolkit-gobject-1-0/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpoppler-glib8/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.10 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

and after some days I will have additional packages installed during the time and requirement.. I have bad habit of editing the package contents just to try different things..

Say while Installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 I have fresh packages of 100nos.. and after some days I have 150nos..

Is there a way to store the package names that are Initially available Just after the fresh Installation of OS. After that prepare a script which will reinstall those packages and remove extra 50pkgs added?

Note: I have High Speed Internet with Required DATA capacity to download/ reinstall all the 100 packages..

Is this Achievable with a script?

like

```
apt purge remove those extra 50 packages added
apt autoremove && apt autoclean
apt install --reinstall those initial 100 packages
```

---

Edit:

1. Installed Ubuntu 18.04.3
2. `apt list --installed`
3. with a script save those packages names only say pkg1 pkg2 .... pkg 99 pkg100.

for example: below lines are some of the output from `apt list --installed`
so I am looking for a way to save the pkg names `zenity zenity-common zip zlib1g` in a text file so that I can use them with `sudo apt install --reinstall zenity zenity-common zip zlib1g`

```
zenity/bionic,now 3.28.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
zenity-common/bionic,bionic,now 3.28.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
zip/bionic,now 3.0-11build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
zlib1g/bionic,now 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

4. work for 1 month..
5. During this 1month I have installed around 50 packages and corrupted some of the packages from initial 100 packages..
6. At this point, I need to `apt install --reinstall those 100 packages` and `apt purge those extra 50 packages added`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99872/discussion-on-question-by-pratap-get-package-names-untouched-after-a-fresh-ins).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Python 3 script which uses Python functions as well as some Bash commands.

#### Pre-requisite:

1. Ubuntu should be installed. Script isn't modified for Kubuntu, Lubuntu or other flavors.
2. [`curl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/curl.1.html) should be installed. If not installed, install it using:

   ```
   sudo apt install curl
   ```
3. User must be using a version that is currently supported, i.e., it should have reached end of standard support.
4. If you are using LTS version, it should be updated to latest point release. For example, at the time of writing this answer, 18.04.3 is released. So, you should be running the same since it's hard to find the manifest for 18.04, 18.04.1 or 18.04.2.
5. Internet connection is required to download the manifest.

#### Python 3 Script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
def main():
    #Find release number
    a=str(subprocess.check_output("lsb_release -sr", shell=True))[2:7]

    #Check if it is LTS
    if(a[3:5]=='04' and int(a[0:2])%2==0):
        print("Since you are using LTS release, is your Ubuntu up to date? Enter 'yes' to continue.", end=" ")
        b=input()
        if(b!='yes'):
            return
        b=str(subprocess.check_output("lsb_release -sd", shell=True))[9:16]

        #Download manifest and extract the package names by removing architecture and version string
        l = os.system('curl -s http://releases.ubuntu.com/' + a + '/ubuntu-' + b + '-desktop-amd64.manifest > 1.txt; sed -i "s/\t.*//g" 1.txt; sed -i "s/:.*//g" 1.txt')
    else:
        l= os.system('curl -s http://releases.ubuntu.com/' + a + '/ubuntu-' + a + '-desktop-amd64.manifest > 1.txt; sed -i "s/\t.*//g" 1.txt; sed -i "s/:.*//g" 1.txt')

    #Get default packages in a set
    packages_initial={line.strip() for line in open("1.txt", 'r')}
    l=os.system('apt list --installed > 2.txt 2> /dev/null; sed -i "s/\/.*//g" 2.txt')

    #Get currently installed packages in a set
    packages_installed={line.strip() for line in open("2.txt", 'r')}

    #Packages that are manually installed
    l=packages_installed-packages_initial

    #Converting list into a string separated by space to pass to APT commands
    to_be_removed=' '.join(l)

    #Package count to be removed
    print(len(l), "packages will be removed.")

    #Removing those packages
    os.system('sudo apt purge '+ to_be_removed+'; sudo apt autoclean; sudo apt autoremove')

    #Install any default package that might have been deleted because of dependencies
    os.system('sudo apt install '+' '.join(packages_initial.intersection(packages_installed)))

    #Cleanup
    os.system('rm 1.txt 2.txt')
main()
```

I have also uploaded this script to GitHub. You can download and run that using

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kulfy1/remove-manually-installed-packages/master/script.py
chmod +x script.py
./script.py
```

#### Explanation:

The above script will download the manifest file which contains the name of packages installed by default. A list will be created which contain those package names. Another list will be created which would contain currently installed package names. APT will remove the packages that were installed manually and are not in the earlier list. After removing the packages, the packages that were common in those lists would be installed, if removed due to some reasons.

#### Footnote:

The prompts of APT commands (such as password and confirmation to remove/install packages) are expected to be handled by the user and aren't being handled in the script since it may happen that user don't want to really remove those packages. Since script isn't run with sudo privileges, thus, no package would be removed by the script unless password and "Yes" are provided when prompted by the APT.

Comment: will try and revert back... thank you..

Comment: I have tried the script.. unfortunately it asked me to remove lot 0f packages other than which I have installed only 4 pkgs after a fresh install 0f Ubuntu 18.04.3.. So I gave permission with Yes.. and I my self Corrupted the OS.. now tired as its night.. tomorrow I will reinstall the 0S.. I have edited Question.. please have a look.. Thank You..

Comment: @PRATAP Before posting I tested it on a fresh install of 19.04. When the script was running, it would have created a file with default packages namely 1.txt. Let me know the content of that file. Was that empty?

Comment: that's nice from you.. I have run your script on 18.04.3.. It gave me that it is going to remove around 1500+ packages will be removed.. so I knew I am giving permission to break my 0S..though I proceed as the laptop is dedicatedly for trails..

Comment: I shall provide you the text file tomorrow @Kulfy

Comment: @PRATAP I re-ran the script in my main installation as well as newly installed 18.04.3. However, handful packages were to be removed.

Comment: 0k.. I will reinstall 18.04.3..then install few packages and shall see again by running the script.. thanks for your time..

Comment: I have downloaded from the git link you provided.. hv you ran the script with wget command or with the script file directly?

Comment: @PRATAP Both are equal. I ran it using ./script.py

Comment: 0.k I shall try tomorrow and get back to you.... GN